# Best way to insert source code blocks in an outline environment

Tags: environments, sourcecode

I had the (somewhat) specialized problem of incorporating source code listings into blocks tagged with `\begin{outline}` etc. I found that `\verbatim` wasn't working for me and so I ended up stuck with the awkwardness of making each source line a `\texttt{}` block. I admit that this is horrifically inelegant, and indenting blocks of code this way (in an outline format that does some automatic indentation for me!) is sheer hell. Yes, I should have come here first and asked...

Anyway, I got it all rendered OK, but found I wanted an i-- (decrement op) in the middle of a simple `\texttt{}` expression in some C source code, and the second '-' would not render. I stuck a {} between the two '-' characters and presto!, it did!

There must be an easier way with than the barebones `\usepackage{outline}` and `\texttt{}` approach, because I ended up putting a lot of source code in my outline. It works (barely!) but I'm interested in discovering an easier approach for next time, including an explanation of how the outline environment is not all that special wrt these changes. I'll say this: I've gotten pretty good at balancing my braces! ;-D

Comment: Have you looked at the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) and [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) packages? Both are great for including source code, with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example of how `outline` works, so that we don't have to learn a new package syntax?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that, Steven: there's a `\usepackage{outline}` in the preamble and then `\begin{outline}` to start each division and `\item` for paragraphs under each division. With each `\end{outline}` you step  up a level, like from (A, B, C) back up to (I, II, III). My understanding is that this only goes 4 levels deep in this simple package. To respond to @Andrew, thanks for making me aware of _listings_ and _minted_.